# Change default path of system images in Android Studio

Tags: android, image, system

I have a ~120 GB SSD in which Android Studio (and Windows 10) is installed. I decided to put it there because I wanted Android Studio to start up quickly, but Android system images, which are quite big, are quickly filling it up and I'll run out of space soon.

Is there a way to change the location of the system images to the storage hard drive, but keep android studio in the SSD? Would I see a noticeable delay in the start up time of the emulators if I do this?

If this can't be done and I have to install Android Studio in the hard drive, would the difference in start up times be too big? I never tried Android Studio in the hard drive before, but it is my understanding that SSDs are considerably quicker than HDDs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the only Android SDK to Hard Drive. Moving Android SDK to hard drive most of space is free in SSD. Put Android studio in SSD and set path of Android SDK in Android studio.